# How to expand an horizontal line to 100% width in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-native

I am using `reactjs` and i am currently unable to expand the horizontal line that i have created below to 100% width.

This is due to the div on top of it that occupy 80% of the screen, therefore my element also has 80%.

Is there anyway that I can expand my element "the horizontal line" to 100% width WITHOUT MODIFYING it parent element?

```js
const HorizontalLine = () => {
  return <section className="line"></section>;
};

export default HorizontalLine;
```

## css

```css
.line {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Below is the structure of the page that I am dealing with. As mentioned above I am not allowed to modify the structure of the parent page.

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="page-title">
            </div>
            <section className="line"</section> # My element is located here
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

## page.css

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

## Ron

Please take a look here i want the line not to be on top of the blue background on the left side. So i am trying to limit as far it can go from the left.

[image]
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say that *div on top of it that occupy 80% of the screen*, do you mean that `div.page` is 80% wide? Can you share the exact styles applied to `div.page`?

Comment: You can use `width: 100vw` which will make the "line" the full width of the screen. However, you'll still start inside the parent container. From there you'll need to add a negative margin to the "line" so that it starts further left than the parent starts.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar please find above the `page.css`

Comment: @JohnD I just noticed your HTML is broken `div.page-title` has no ending tag. Is it the case with the actual code or just on your SO post?

Comment: <section className="line"</section> your markup need to update    <section className="line"> </section>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the line to break out from the current section, and be fill-page-width, add these to the `.line` class:

```
.line{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

You can additionally add `width:100vw;` to ensure that the line covers 100 virtual width of the page.

Comment: my hero! is there a way i could limit or edit the left side of the line?

Comment: you can push left: with `left: 10px;` for example.. not sure what exactly you need to do.

Comment: Can you take a look at the post above i have added a small image of what i am referring and mentioned your name. maybe you could give me your feedback. thank you a lot.

Comment: Oh, to put the line under the blue "section", use  `z-index: 10` for the line itself in CSS, and set the `z-index:` to something bigger than 10 (the z-index of the line) so set the blue as something like: `z-index:15` for example... or bigger

Comment: i tried it before, the way the blue "section" is built, `z-index` doesnt work when i try on `line`. thanks for your help if you have any other suggestion i would love to hear them otherwise thanks

Comment: If you provide a working layout in codepen.io for example, I can try to help, but with screenshots I do not see what you have set, so not sure what to suggest exactly :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this on `.line`:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 100%;
```

but that will have an impact on the other children of `.page`, they will shrink

Comment: This answer does not make the line fill page with

Comment: it will be 100% of the width within a flex container (row), not more and not less, and `.page` is a flex container. It that doesn't work that means some context is missing in the question and interfere with it.
But have it positionned absolute can work too if you prefer, but that might overlap the following elements :)